# Europe cluster availabe for europe� its also used for cloud storage and gmail?

Tags: security, google-app-engine, data-protection

With release 1.7 of appengine sdk it specifies that europe cluster is available. But Does this cluster used for all google services as Drive  or gmail? It is an important point for europe laws about privicy and data protection.

Regards

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal and privacy issues concerning Google services, not about actual programming with them.

Answer (score 2):

This announcement only refers to data stored by App Engine apps and does not apply other Google services such as Drive or gmail.

update (to include Guido's comment): "What we store in EU at rest: datastore, blobstore, logs."

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/premier/location for details:

> """ Locating your application in the European Union is especially
>   useful if your application's users are closer to Europe than to the
>   United States. There is less network latency and the End User Content
>   will be stored at rest in the European Union. """

and

> """ While your Application will be run out of a datacenter in the
>   location you have chosen, please be aware that Google may process and
>   store the Application and Customer Content in the United States or any
>   other country in which Google or its agents maintain facilities. """

Comment: """For more information about the storage of End User Content, please contact your sales representative."""  (Note that the EU feature is for Premier customers only, so you should always know how to reach your sales rep.)

Comment: What we store in EU at rest: datastore, blobstore, logs.